# pods keep creating themselves even I deleted all deployments

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I am running k8s on aws, and I updated the deployment of nginx - which normally, it works fine-, but after this time, the nginx deployment won't show up in "kubectl get deployments".

I want to kill all the pods related to nginx, but they keep reproduce themselves. I deleted all deployments "kubectl delete --all deployments", other pods just got terminated, but not nginx.

I have no idea where I can stop the pods recreating.
any idea where to start ?

Comment: Is there still a replication controller?

Answer (score 4):

check the deployment, replication controller and replica set and remove them.

```
 kubectl  get deploy,rc,rs
```

Comment: Or, if your cluster is small enough, `kubectl get --all-namespaces --show-all all` will output every resources k8s knows about

Comment: Thank you , yes I found it in rc . I deleted rc nginx, and all is good.

Answer (score 0):

In modern kubernetes, there is also an annotation `kubernetes.io/created-by` on the Pod showing its "owner", [as seen here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/v1.7.3/pkg/api/v1/annotation_key_constants.go#L50), but I can't lay my hands on the documentation link right now. However, I found a [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/MsibJgkZ) containing a concrete example of the contents of the annotation